# WebBrowser don't show full output of pythont CGI programm

Tags: python, ubuntu, cgi

I use Python3 and CGI to display bus lines to my Web Browser. But the browser dont get the hole HTML Script somehow. Here is my Code(Python):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import dvb
import sys

stop = 'Hauptbahnhof'
time_offset = 0
num_results =5
city = 'Dresden'

output=dvb.monitor(stop, time_offset, num_results, city)
#print(output)
print("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n")
print("<html><body>")
i=0
for items in output:
    print("<p>")
    print(str(output[i]['line']))
    print(str(output[i]['direction']))
    print(str(output[i]['arrival']))
    print("</p>")
    i=i+1
print("</html></body>")
```

When I execute it in console I get this Output:

```
Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8


<html><body>
<p>
64
Striesen
0
</p>
<p>
79
Übigau
1
</p>
<p>
64
Kaditz, Riegelplatz
2
</p>
<p>
4
Laubegast
3
</p>
<p>
9
Prohlis
4
</p>
</body></html>
```

When I call the file in the Browser I get this Sourcecode:

```
<html><body>
<p>
64
Striesen
0
</p>
<p>
79
```

So the Soucecode didn't get transfered correctly, but why?

Some more technical informations:
-Virtiual Box
-ubuntu-18.04.1-dekstop-amd64

Edit:
I use apache2/2.4.29.
Her is my apache2 Virtiual Host Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName busLinien
    ServerAdmin jofri@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/busLinien
    <Directory /var/www/busLinien>
            AllowOverride None
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
            Options ExecCGI
            AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
```

Comment: The issue is more likely your web-server software (Apache/nginx/lighttpd) and how it is configured. Please show which web-server you use and the corresponding config file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated my post. Is this the config which are you looking for?

Comment: Try using `"Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell No still the same Problem. But its weird sometimes the website shows the hole source code. And sometimes only the first 2 lines. Im confused

Comment: Your `<html><body>` needs to come **before** any other HTML.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yea, I already noticed and fixed that. But the Problem is not solved. Sorry for not updating the picture

Comment: Code is up to date now

Comment: Please remove the picture of the output and replace it with a copied and pasted version of the output as actual text. Es ist richtig schwer Woerter in einem Bild zu suchen!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated the Post

Comment: Both examples you have shown have stopped abruptly on the first line that includes German characters such as diaresis (umlaut) and `ö`. The issue is almost certainly related to Unicode encoding.

Comment: Oh yea I didn't saw that. But I currently can't figure out how to fix it. I tried using  "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n" but nothing changed